# Custom maven repo grails 3

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Has anybody has and success installing the Cloudinary plugin in a Grails 3 application.

The plugin instructions are here and I've made the modifications I think are correct for Grails 3 : https://bitbucket.org/sbuettner/grails-cloudinary

Below is the build.grade file

However, the grails command line util reports :

| Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

        // Custom maven repo for the cloudinary plugin
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/infinit/infinit-opensource"     }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
}

version "0.1"
group "mchq.admin"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

    // Custom maven repo for the cloudinary plugin
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/infinit/infinit-opensource" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    // https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#tutorials
    // "Install" the plugin by adding it to build.gradle
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'

    // https://grails.org/plugin/mail
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602032/grails-3-mail-plugin-not-working
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC2"

    // https://bitbucket.org/sbuettner/grails-cloudinary
    compile "grails-cloudinary:0.3"

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help but it was the following to fix it :

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-cloudinary:0.3"
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Fixed it with adding my repo like this:

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" } //default
   maven { url "http://myCompanyDev1/nexus/content/groups/public/" } // my companies repo / nexus
}
```

And included it like this:

```
dependencies { 
    compile 'de.myCompany.projects.intern:ld-grails-modules:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT@zip'
}
```

Notice the "@zip" in the end. Default seems to be "jar" but there was no jar on our nexus, only the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `maven { url "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact" }` to the `repositories` list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the same problem remains.  When you say add it to repositories list, which do you mean and in what positions within those lists?  There is 'repositories' within build script as well as another 'root' level one lower down....